# Generating subtitle in different language of Video where audio could be in different language

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am able to generate vtt file using azure media service transform job. but I have a requirement where in my input video file's audio could be in English language and I want to generate vtt file in Spanish language. I tried passing language to preset and in generated VTT file also says NOTE language:es-es  but the VTT file content is not as per the audio.

could you please assist what could go wrong here ?

Comment: @johndeu .. could you please assist ?

Comment: Link to sample code - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/AudioAnalytics/index.ts#L84 

But David is correct below, we do not do "translation" or text-to-text.  For that feature, look at Azure Video Analytics for Media (formerly known as Video Indexer)

Answer (score 0):

In Media Services the language setting for the AudioAnalyzerPreset is there to help describe the input.  According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/analyze-video-audio-files-concept, "Specify the language for the audio payload in the input using the BCP-47 format of 'language tag-region'." Media Services does not offer translation. For that you could use something like Video Indexer (https://videoindexer.ai) that generates VTT files and translates them as well.

Comment: Sample code in Typescript for setting the language, and using preset overrides on a per-job basis are here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/AudioAnalytics/index.ts#L84

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. i understand that media service does not offer translation of my captions.  i have few questions .. 1) Since i  have English caption file now , can i parse my file and use cognitive service to translate it. I am concerned about the quality here. Also i have cognitive service subscription already and i am using it as well. So if i use Video Indexer now i think we will have a pricing difference

Comment: what is your suggestion . Either i parse my caption file and translate via cognitive service or use media indexer ?  also do we have some c# sample code for media indexer